# stxxl map<int, string>

Tags: database, indexing, spatial, stxxl

I am looking for a storage to index points in 2 dimensions. To be more
specific, I would like to store the geometry of ways (or edges) in OpenStreetMap
and have it searchable. Queries to the storage would be looking up geometry based on two endpoints of a way. This query would be run to reconstruct the geometry of a path found
by an algorithm similar to Dijkstra, so the speed of geometry lookup is important.

Nodes in my case are just unsigned ints and geometry can be encoded as a string or
as a vector of points, either way would work.

The number of nodes would be around 1 billion so keeping everything in memory does not work, so it would be nice to find an external or disk based storage.

I have already tried Stxxl but it doesn't seem to support non-POD types like string or
vectors as values.

Thanks for suggestions in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate map like behavior by maintaining two separate vectors. Say, you have two `<key, value>` pairs `<0, "hello">`, `<1, "world">`. The first `vector (of char)` then contains,

```
h, e, l, l, o, \0, w, o, r, l, d, \0
```

The second `vector (of pair of two 'size_type's)` contains the `begin position` and `one past end position` of each `string` like this,

```
<0, 6>, <6, 12>
```

As you can see, it is not required that `"world"` comes after `"hello"`. That way, for any new  `<key, value>` pair, you just update the ***start and end position*** in the second vector (*indexed access*), and you put the value at the ***end*** of the first vector (*no shifting required*).

EDIT: Instead of the `vector (of pair of two 'size_type's)`, you can also use `map< int, pair<size_type, size_type> >` which makes up for a better solution I guess. Take your pick.